# Dataset and values on MS Report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, charts, dataset

1. Added DataSet Add->New Item
2. Create DataTable1 on DataSet1
3. Added two columns ValueA, ValueB both int16
   [image]
4. Added two values by using this code on Form Load.

   ```
     Dim workRow As DataRow = DataSet1.DataTable1.NewRow()
       DataSet1.DataTable1.Rows.Add(New Object() {270, 300})
   ```
5. Added a ReportViewer on Form2
6. Created the Report and put the values from datasource on it.
   [image]

   When i run the program it won't show me the values on report :S :S :S

If someone can edit this links and put images instead

[image]