# VIsual Studio Windows name

Tags: vb.net

Example i go to `Data < Add new DataSource`and when i add it it should show me this window under but it wont.

Also when i try `Toolbox < Menu Strip` i cant find it downthere to edit or delete.

How is this window called and how to show it/ view

Because of this problem [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361113/dataset-and-values-on-ms-report) i will go and use database to store and transfer value.

[image]

Comment: It is not a speparate window, it is a panel within the form's window. You can change the size of this lower panel. Is it possible that it has size 0? Try to move the mouse pointer to the lower edge and see whether you can resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not another window, but a panel thats displays components within the WinForms designer window. It is not displayed when you add a DataSource, but when you drop a component from the toolbox or a column from the DataSource onto the form itself for the first time. I.E. you don't need to see it in order to do that, just drag and drop a column to your window and it will appear automatically.

Comment: it wont show like that i tried x times. I accidentally undocked the errors window and resized that window to min

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Olivier i "undocked" this windows so i wasn't been enabled to find it

[image]